# Service Role ARN blank in CodeDeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to setup the CodeDeploy service with one of my ec2 instances. On the form to do this, everything works properly until I reach the "Service Role" section.

This field does not display any possible ARNs.

This is what I see:

[image: img]

I created an IAM user and gave them Admin privileges and pasted their ARN into this field and got the error message

> Cannot assume role provided.

Does anyone know the reason this is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You skipped step 3 in the Getting Started guide: [Create a Service Role](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/how-to-create-service-role.html).

Comment: Actually it isn't working properly. I was successful in creating another role but I am still receiving the same "Cannot Assume Role" message. The role I created is now viewable in this field. I gave it proper privileges to Code Deploy so that is out of the question.

Comment: I added the Administrator policy to the role I created, maybe it doesn't like such a powerful policy.

Comment: Where are you getting the "Cannot Assume Role" message?  When you try to create the deployment or later on?

Comment: Its happening when I try to create the development group. I can't even deploy because I get the error and it doesn't let me create the group.

Comment: Did you create the instance profile, as described here?  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/how-to-create-iam-instance-profile.html

Comment: Yeah I did. I also attached it to my instance. I'm sure of this as it is shown in the EC2 dashboard. The profile should have the required privelages.
http://i.imgur.com/NgsPs1h.png

Comment: And you gave it the AssumeRole policy as shown in the link above?  Because that error comes from not giving a resource the trust permission of the role it's trying to assume.

Comment: I think I didn't create the profile properly. I think I need to be in the Policies submenu of IAM on the site ( I was in the roles submenu)

Comment: It was just an issue with being confused and not following the tutorial properly. I am launching a new instance with the new profile and I will see how it works. Thanks Karen for your help.

Answer (score 9):

I had to add "codedeploy.amazonaws.com" to the Role Trust Relationships:

```
    {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "codedeploy.amazonaws.com",
          "ec2.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```